# Android: SQLite, cursor.moveToNext() always returns false

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

The following statement `cursor.moveToNext()` is always false. I expect the loop to execute once. I've tested that the query actually returns data.

Does anyone know what is the matter?

```
    String query ="SELECT(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) as count1, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2) as count2;";

    Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {   //<---------------return false here???
        String result_0=cursor.getString(0);
    }
```

Comment: Is it related to without using the "FROM" in the query statement so that SQLite can't identify it as a vaild comand?

Comment: nop ...your query should return only one row so when you use cursor.moveToFirst() you are at first row ... now any call moveToNext() will return false ... mCursor should never be null so use smth like `if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){do{/*String res... your stuff*/}while(mCursor.moveToNext());}else{/*cursor has no rows should not happend*/}` or in this case(since it should return only 1 row `if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){/*String res... your stuff*/}else{/*cursor has no rows WTF?*/}`

Comment: i love you baby. problem solved!!! After removing cursor.moveToFirst()...... haha

Answer (score 4):

I know you've solved your problem, but here is a walkthrough of what happened:

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);

// At this point mCursor is positioned at just before the first record.

if (mCursor != null) {
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    // mCursor is now pointing at the first (and only) record
}

while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
    String result_0=cursor.getString(0);
}

// The loop above was skipped because `.moveToNext()` caused mCursor
// to move past the last record.
```

So, in your case of only needing a single record, you only need either `mCursor.moveToFirst()` *OR* your `mCursor.moveToNext()`.

Answer (score 4):

you can iterate cursor this way.

```
    if(moveCursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            //your code

        }while(moveCursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: I've read that `getCount()` is an expensive operation so it is probably wise to avoid it if you can (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16186513/1084488).

Comment: Nevermind my above comment, after reviewing the Android source code I've found out that pretty much all cursor operations (including `moveToFirst()`, `moveToNext()`, `isBeforeFirst()` and `isFirst()`) will result in at least 1 call to `getCount()`.
So even if `getCount()` is expensive it is unavoidable. Moreover, I've also found that the implementation of `getCount()` caches the returned value, so at least subsequent calls will be cheap.