# How to send email of SQLite database using Intent.EXTRA_TEXT?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent, cursor

I am trying to simply send an email with the data from my database as text in the email.

I have searched a ton of posts, and do not want to send as an attachment, I do not want to save to external storage etc. and cannot find what I am looking for.

I would like all the rows from the database to populate, but can only manage to get a single row.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                String[] projection = {
                        LogEntry._ID,
                        LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_DATE,
                        LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_DESTINATION,
                        LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_PURPOSE,
                        LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_MILEAGE};


                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        LogEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                        projection,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

                //TODO ???????????? I want the cursor to continue and get all the data from the database???
                //This is the current result in the email.
                // 1
                // 05 Mar 2018
                // 12:10:52 PM
                // 0
                // 0
                // 88031


                // Extract the properties from cursor
                // Find columns of log attributes that I am interested in
                int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(LogEntry._ID);
                int dateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_DATE);
                int destinationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_DESTINATION);
                int purposeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_PURPOSE);
                int mileageColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_MILEAGE);

                String id = cursor.getString(idColumnIndex);
                String date = cursor.getString(dateColumnIndex);
                int destination = cursor.getInt(destinationColumnIndex);
                int purpose = cursor.getInt(purposeColumnIndex);
                String mileage = cursor.getString(mileageColumnIndex);


                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"recipent@gmail.com"});
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "All Logs for " + LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_DATE);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, id + "\n" + date + "\n" + destination + "\n" + purpose + "\n" + mileage);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Select App"));
```

Comment: You would loop over the `Cursor` to get all of its rows, and use a `StringBuilder` to build up the overall text. See methods like `moveToNext()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for the fast reply.  So I looked into this and used this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/12728360. I am still messing with it, trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You CommonsWare for answering this question. I indeed used the Stringbuilder and it worked flawlessly. Exactly what I wanted.

Here is the code now.

```
     @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String[] projection = {
                        LogEntry._ID,
                        LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_DATE,
                        LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_DESTINATION,
                        LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_PURPOSE,
                        LogEntry.COLUMN_LOG_MILEAGE};


                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        LogEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                        projection,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

                //if the cursor isn't null we will essentially iterate over rows and then columns
                //to form a table of data as per database.
                if (cursor != null) {

                    //more to the first row
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    //iterate over rows
                    for (int index = 0; index < cursor.getCount(); index++) {

                        //iterate over the columns
                        for(int j = 0; j < cursor.getColumnNames().length; j++){

                            //append the column value to the string builder and delimit by a pipe symbol
                            stringBuilder.append(cursor.getString(j) + " | ");
                        }
                        //add a new line carriage return
                        stringBuilder.append("\n");

                        //move to the next row
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                    //close the cursor
                    cursor.close();
                }



                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"recipent@gmail.com"});
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Logs for " + ;
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stringBuilder.toString()); //id + "\n" + date + "\n" + destination + "\n" + purpose + "\n" + mileage);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Select App"));
```